# Access to overridden methods

Tags: c#, oop, overriding, overloading

There is an exercise ["OverloadResolutionOverride"](https://problembook.net/content/en/Oop/OverloadResolutionOverride-P.html)

What will be the output of the following code:

```
class Foo
{
  public virtual void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo.Quux(int)");
  }
}
class Bar : Foo
{
  public override void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar.Quux(int)");
  }
  public void Quux(object a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar.Quux(object)");
  }
}
class Baz : Bar
{
  public override void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Baz.Quux(int)");
  }
  public void Quux<T>(params T[] a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Baz.Quux(params T[])");
  }
}
void Main()
{
  new Bar().Quux(42);
  new Baz().Quux(42);
}
```

There answer is:

> ```
> Bar.Quux(object)
> Baz.Quux(params T[])
> ```

There is an [explanation](https://problembook.net/content/en/Oop/OverloadResolutionOverride-S.html) on the site:

> If compiler found a suitable signature for a method
>   call in the “current” class, compiler will not look to parents
>   classes.

Is it considered that the overloaded Quux(int) method is in the base class, and not in the current one? If so, how i can call exactly Quux(int) method in current class?

Comment: The terms are base and derived class. It is true, that overridden functions completely replace the base class functions. But for that overriding must be **explicitly** allowed by the baseclass (virtual, abstract or previous override).If want the base classes fucntions, call it with base.[classname]().

Comment: @Christopher no, i want to know how can i call method Quux(int) from derived class, because the usual way doesn't work

Comment: Wich Quux(int) do you want to call from wich Quux(int) or wich otehr function? Add the class names to properly idebtify wich override of the Quxx(int) function you are talking about.

Comment: @Christopher I want to call Quux(int) from Bar or Baz in Main function.

Comment: Your code above already does that. What is happening or not happening?

Comment: @Christopher I pass an integer to a function, but it does not call Quux(int), it calls Quux<T>(params T[] a) in Baz or Quux(object a) in Bar

Comment: Okay, I just tested it. This behavior is indeed rather odd. It even happens when I explicitly cast the constant to integer. Even to my knowledge teh output should be "Bar.Quux(int) " and "Baz.Quux(int)". I wonder what here could trip up the compiler in picking the wrong functions?

Comment: Maybe restart it as a new question reading "derived class overload takes precendence before override" with the expect and real output. I doubt this question will get a lot of attention.

Comment: @Christopher Check out the solution I found out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely an interesting effect of what happens when the compiler does its method resolution.

Let's go to the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#method-invocations) and see what we can get out of that (This is my understanding and I am by no means an expert in reading the specification, so if I got something wrong, please let me know!).

The first step is to find methods that have parameters that are [Applicable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#applicable-function-member) with the first bullet reading:

> Each argument in A [Where A is the argument list] corresponds to a parameter in the function member
>   declaration as described in Corresponding parameters, and any
>   parameter to which no argument corresponds is an optional parameter.

So now we go check out what a [Corresponding parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#corresponding-parameters) is and we get:

> For virtual methods and indexers defined in classes, the parameter
>   list is picked from the most specific declaration or override of the
>   function member, starting with the static type of the receiver, and
>   searching through its base classes.

And we also have

> For all other function members and delegates there is only a single
>   parameter list, which is the one used.

Therefore, for the class `Bar`, we find two methods the fit the bill:

1. `Bar.Quux(object)`. This is from the second paragraph because it is defined on the type directly.
2. `Foo.Quux(int)`. This is from the derived type by following the override up to the `virtual` method declaration.

For the `Baz` class we get 3:

1. `Baz.Quux(int[])`. This is defined on the type.
2. `Bar.Quux(object)`. This is defined in a parent class and is visible to the scope of `Baz`.
3. `Foo.Quux(int)`. This is the virtual declaration of the override.

This gives us 2 method matches in `Bar`, and 3 possible method matches in `Baz`. This means we need to do further culling of the parameter set with the following next set (Emphasis mine):

> The set of candidate methods is **reduced to contain only methods from
>   the most derived types**: For each method C.F in the set, where C is the
>   type in which the method F is declared, **all methods declared in a base
>   type of C are removed from the set**. Furthermore, if C is a class type
>   other than object, all methods declared in an interface type are
>   removed from the set. (This latter rule only has affect when the
>   method group was the result of a member lookup on a type parameter
>   having an effective base class other than object and a non-empty
>   effective interface set.)

Therefore, for `Bar`, we will cull `Foo.Quux(int)` because it is declared in a base type and is therefore removed from the set.

For `Baz`, we remove the following two methods because they are both declared in base types:

1. `Bar.Quux(object)`
2. `Foo.Quux(int)`

Now, each set has only one method, and we can execute the two methods `Bar.Quux(object)` and `Baz.Quux<int>(int[])`.

### Picking the right Method

So this begs the question, can we force the correct method to be called? And based on the second resolution step, where it uses the most derived type, the answer is that yes we can.

If we want to call `Foo`'s methods, we need to set the type of our caller to `Foo`. If we want `Baz` to call `Bar`'s method, then we will need to set `Baz` to `Bar`.

Considering the following set of method calls:

```
new Bar().Quux(42);
new Baz().Quux(42);
((Foo)new Bar()).Quux(42);
((Foo)new Baz()).Quux(42);
((Bar)new Baz()).Quux(42);
```

We get the following output:

```
Bar.Quux(object)
Baz.Quux(params T[])
Bar.Quux(int)
Baz.Quux(int)
Bar.Quux(object)
```

And are able to target the specific methods that we want to using a similar method resolution as above.

### One More Step

If we change the definition of `Baz` to be following:

```
class Baz : Bar
{
  public override void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Baz.Quux(int)");
  }
}
```

And then make the method call: `new Baz().Quux(42);` our output is still: `Bar.Quux(object)`. This seems strange because of the fact that we have a method override defined within `Baz` directly. However, the originating type for the method is `Foo` which is less specific than `Bar`. So when we match our parameter lists, we end up with `Bar.Quux(object)` and `Foo.Quux(int)` since the `int` parameter list is defined on `Foo`. Therefore, `Foo.Quux(int)` is culled in the second step since `Bar` is more derived than `Foo`, and we call `Bar.Quux(object)`.

I think the moral of the story here is don't name methods the same as overrides!

Answer (score 2):

As other note, the way to call the method you wan't is to downcast: `(Bar)(new Baz).Quux(42);`.

But *why* does the compiler choose the generic method? Isn't an exact non generic match preferred over a generic method when resolving method resolution?

Yes, but another rule applies here too; method resolution will prefer the *nearest* applicable method, nearest meaning where the method is declared in relation to the callsite.

Uhm... `Quux(int)` is declared in `Baz` so I'm not really sure...

No! Overriden methods belong to the class that implements the virtual method; in this case, as far as the compiler is concerned, the "owner" of `Quux` is `Foo`, not `Baz`.

And why would the compiler apply such a rule? Well, suppose the following scenario:

Company Alpha publishes a class `A`:

```
class A { ... }
```

And company Beta goes ahead and consumes `A` by extending it with `B`:

```
class B: A { 
    public void Frob<T>(T frobbinglevel) { ... }
    ... }
```

Everything is honky dory and Beta is having tremendous success with its brilliant frobbing. Company Alpha decides to have a go with its own frobbing and publishes a new version of `A`:

```
class A { 
    public virtual void Frob(int frobbinglevel) { ... }
    ... }
```

Beta recompiles its library with Alpha's updates and now what should happen? Should the compiler start choosing `A.Frob(1)` over `B.Frob(1)`, `A.Frob` is a non generic exact match?

But hey... Beta hasn't changed anything and now its class is not working as it should! Suddenly, without any change in its code, method resolution is choosing different methods, breaking its customers...that doesn't seem right. This is the reason why the rule exists.

Answer (score 1):

To call exactly Quux(int) from Bar or Baz you should cast Bar or Baz to Foo:

```
Foo bar = new Bar();
Foo baz = new Baz();
bar.Quux(42); 
baz.Quux(42);
```

The output:

> ```
> Bar.Quux(int)
> Baz.Quux(int)
> ```